# How to change material color (LWRP)

Tags: unity, c#

I've upgraded my project to LWRP, I've changed my materials to: LWRP/lit. But in one of the gamemodes i need to change one my materials' color by script. I used to do it simply like `wallMat.color = Color.red`, but at LWRP that code doesn't work, how to fix it?

**Edit:** LWRP = Light Weight Render Pipeline

Comment: Have you tried [Material Property Blocks](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html) for this purpose?

Comment: Isn't that needs custom shader? Custom shaders not displays materials if you have LWRP.

Comment: No, it doesn't require a custom shader, as shown below - it works with the default Lit shader that the LWRP uses. If you'd tried using MaterialPropertyBlocks, you would have been able to discover that for yourself even faster. Remember, we don't have access to some secret version of Unity that you don't - anything we suggest, you can try *right now* without waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a [MaterialPropertyBlock](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html), just like you would in the old pipeline to reduce the overhead of instantiating modified copies of materials. The only difference is that the shader property is called "_BaseColor" not "_Color":

```
// You can re-use this block between calls rather than constructing a new one each time.
var block = new MaterialPropertyBlock();

// You can look up the property by ID instead of the string to be more efficient.
block.SetColor("_BaseColor", Color.red);

// You can cache a reference to the renderer to avoid searching for it.
GetComponent<Renderer>().SetPropertyBlock(block);
```

Comment: It works very well on the gameobjects but can you tell me how can i change my characters material with that? It uses skinned mesh renderer on his child game object so i wrote smth like this: `player.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>().SetPropertyBlock(block);` but it didn't work.

Comment: Does your character have multiple materials on it? If so, you may need to pass a material index as the second argument to target the desired material. It's also possible that your character shader's colour property is named something else.

Comment: It's LWRP/lit and i only have one material.

Comment: Then it sounds like you should make a minimal complete verifiable example and post it as a new question.

Comment: I can't post my own made character that i am going to publish in my game?

Comment: If you can't post that, then produce a new minimal complete verifiable example that you can post, using a free publicly available asset or a dummy asset that you can walk us through how to create (eg. even a basic cube will let you demonstrate whether a material change works)

Comment: Hi there, the above suggestion clearly works on `SetColor`, however, if I decide to get the color **prior** doing **SetColor** as described above I always get 0. This is my method, let me know what I am doing wrong: ````public static Color GetColor(GameObject go) {
        MaterialPropertyBlock block = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
        go.GetComponent<Renderer>().GetPropertyBlock(block);
        return block.GetColor("_BaseColor");
    }````

Comment: @angeltodorov That sounds like a new question. Click the "Ask Question" button at the top of the site/app to post it as its own Q&A thread. The short answer: if you haven't set a colour on a material property block on a material, of course it won't contain one. Ask the material if you want its base colour, not the non-existent property block.

Answer (score 7):

This works fine as well:

`material.SetColor("_BaseColor", color);`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried matName.CopyPropertiesFromMaterial(otherMatName); and it worked! Creating another materials isn't the best way but in my case i've already had those materials and this way was the solution for me.